# group by with year of the date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a date column in excel,with year_month_day format I want to extract only year of my date and group the column by year,but I got an error

```
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[18], format='%y/%m/%d %I:%M%p')
df.groupby(by=[df.index.year])
```

18 is index of my date column

error=ValueError: time data '2022/04/23' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %I:%M%p' (match)

I don't know how can I fix it.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - the time data doesn't match the format. Are all your dates in the same format?

Comment: As @topsail said, the error is self-explanatory. Try to change the format to '%Y/%m/%d'.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the error message indicates that the format string you are using,  `%y/%m/%d %I:%M%p`, doesn't match the format of the dates in your column.

It appears that your date format is `YYYY/MM/DD`, but the format string you're using is trying to parse it as `YY/MM/DD %I:%M%p`.

I think you should change the format string to `%Y/%m/%d`.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[18], format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Then you can extract the year using the year attribute of the datetime object, and group by the year as you are doing.

Make sure your date column is formatted correctly. I provide here a code with which you can adjust the format of the dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022/04/23', '2022/04/24', '2022/04/25']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: I did what you said but error changed to    pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1401-04-23 00:00:00 present at position 0

Comment: The following error message is indicating that there are invalid dates (dates out of the range of the minimum and maximum dates supported by Pandas) in the column. To identify and replace the disabled dates by NaT (Not a Time), you can use the following code:

df[18] = pd.to_datetime(df[18], errors='coerce')
df[18].fillna(value=pd.NaT, inplace=True)
df.index = df[18]
df.groupby(by=[df.index.year]).sum()